# android: How to draw line on a canvas that changes size on the basis of touch speed

Tags: android, android-view

I want to draw a line on a canvas and have the line change size according my draw speed.

If  I draw fast, the line size should be small, if I draw slowly, the line should be bigger.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the line to be thicker if you draw slowly, or longer, or both?  Also, do you have any code you've tried so far?

Comment: Yes,That's my want .I've tried a number of ways, what I can't do.I want the line to be thicker if I draw slowly, and the line to be thiner if I draw faster.

Comment: actually , I want to make bamboo brush.

Comment: I think you're going to need to be more detailed about what you're trying to do, and what code you've used so far to do it.  Otherwise I think the problem is too open-ended and you may not get much useful feedback.

Comment: just like "Line Brush"Application,in this application,have many paint brush,I want to customer paint brush.